# jQuery (or other) multiple choice quiz with different outcomes

Tags: jquery, multiple-choice

I've been coding jQuery for a while but I have never approached a quiz before.

Basically, I am trying to make a quiz like the multiple choice ones you get as a kid - if you've answered majority A, you get a certain outcome, but if you are majority B you get a different outcome etc...

Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this? Because so far I've only encountered tutorials that show you how to assign a value to a checkbox and then calculate a numerical answer. However, I can't figure out how to apply this to non-numerical id's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What mark-up are you working with, just for the sake of an example.

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/jquizzy-premium-quiz-engine/242295?redirect_back=true&ref=jtop&clickthrough_id=23772760 perhaps you could purchase this and review the code

Comment: Could you provide a more specific example of your quiz? i.e. sample questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Java Script to assign to arbitrary properties of an appropriately named variable.

```
var answers = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0,
    c: 0
};

function answer(answer){
    exec('answers.' answer.toLowerCase() + ' += 1;');
}
```

Comment: A quiz with this format: 

http://www.blogthings.com/whatcolorcrayonareyouquiz/

So you choose answers from the multiple choice questions and then depending on if you've answered majority A, B, C etc, you get a specific answer.